# iOS: How can I remove reference to sub-views?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm creating an app that has hundreds of view controllers in interface-builder.  Each of these view controllers has a button with a code number. When the button is pressed I want the button to expand and show a few lines of text describing the code number.  The problem is that the button is placed within a subview that acts as a frame for the button. Therefore, the expanded button size is going to be constrained to that subview and the text will be cutoff.  Is there a way for me to programmatically remove the reference to the sub-view?  I can do this in interface-builder, but like I said there are hundreds of these view controllers.

Comment: OT: Hundreds of view controllers? That means hundreds of different design/usage patterns... Are you sure that you need that many and not just have one and fill in different data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead I removing it you could **expand the subView**'s *and* the `UIButton`'s width. That would allow the button to expand as you'd like it to and you would not have to remove the subViews.

Comment: That would work except we already connected the buttons to our custom class and connecting all the subviews too would just take more time.  This project has just become a big mess.  Is there a way to easy hook in all the subviews to the custom class?

Comment: I would suggest simply deleting all the ViewControllers and creating a label & button that change their content.